# Alternative to Response.Redirect in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, authorization

I am working with middleware .net core web application, I am trying to redirect un authorized user /Account/Login, I am try to use following code which is not working fine.

```
    public async static void Athenticate(HttpContext context)
    {

        if (/*unauthorized user*/)
        {
            //destroy session Redirect user to login page
            context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login");
        }
    }
```

Comment: There's a redirect method on the controller class. Also don't use async void lol

Comment: What exactly is "not working"?

Comment: If you're not seeing "authorization" data for the user, maybe you need to add app.UseAuthentication(); before adding reference to your middleware "Use" in Startup.cs

Comment: Don’t redirect manually for authentication, and don’t do authentication yourself. Integrate the auth stack and use it properly. Just return a challenge result from your middleware and let MVC handle that to redirect to the login.

Comment: context.Response.Redirect("/Account/Login"); is not redirecting to login action.

Comment: Tseng! I am not working in controller class.

Comment: I am having a similar issue with context.Response.Redirect not working correctly. @saif did you find a solution for this?

Comment: @saif - did you find a solution for this?